# How to make a character jump in C#/Direct X 9.0?

Tags: c#, 2d, directx-9

I am currently making a game in C# using Direct X 9.0. I have nearly everything completed, but I am having problems with the physics of the jump. I have variables declared for the Y and X coordinates.

I was wondering if there was a simple method of doing this. I have searched high and low for an answer but the answers I have found are either irrelevant/ or using a different programming language such as XNA.

I currently have a bool variable set to check to see if `W` has been pressed which triggers any code to make him jump. I have been messing around such as.

```
if (Form1.jump == true)
{
    Playerypos = Playerypos - vel;
    Playerxpos = Playerxpos + vel;
    //Form1.jump = false;
}
```

Which didn't work that well.

Comment: Im sure the guys here could help, but maybe better off over here as its game specific: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `if (Form1.jump == true) `ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

You need a little more for jumping than for moving around: you need the concept of acceleration.

Basically when you detect the jump key pressed you set your vertical acceleration to some positive value. Your physics loop will have to be changed to constantly add your acceleration to your position, and then add gravity to your acceleration (thus decreasing it then turn it negative to land back down). Clamp your position to your land/plane/lowest position possible(*) and you're set!

(*) Never as easy as it looks, you'll have to implement some kind of raycasting algorithm here because you'll jump in large-ish increments and could fall through the ground. Think box-intersects-line instead of point-in-line.